# How to export stored procedures from my mysql database

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, stored-procedures

I have 3 stored procedures in my server db. I want to get all the procedures and import to my local server.

So i run the following query to get the create procedure

```
show create PROCEDURE `procInsertDefaultItemsToCart`
```

When i run the query i got the following output

[image]

My create procedure is NULL. So how can i get the create procedure query. please guide me anyone.

I want get this procedures from my server.

Answer (score 1):

If your login does not have enough privileges, the "show create"-command will now NULL as procedure code. Use the login that was used to create the routine (or use root-user).

Answer (score 1):

Did you try with mysql dump yet?
Here is a blog post with some details on how to get all the SPs included in your mysql dump: https://programalitics.substack.com/p/mysql-database-export-tips

Summary: `mysqldump -u [username] -p --routines --events DatabaseName > backupsqlfile.sql`